# How can I make a GtkTreeView work with a vertical scrollbar in Glade3?

Tags: gtk, scrollbar, glade, gtktreeview

I'm using glade 3, to create TreeView and successfully added row as algorithm done, but I had a little issue because treeview will add new row, thus my "GUI" will getting longer to the below, how could I add the scrollbar for this TreeView? in order to make my "GUI" not getting any longer?

Note: I have added "a new adjustment" and connected it for TreeView and ScrollBar vertical as well, but still not get the job done.

any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try putting your TreeView into a [GtkScrolledWindow](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkScrolledWindow.html).  E.g.:

```xml
<child>
  <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="hscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
    <property name="vscrollbar_policy">automatic</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTreeView" id="items_view">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="model">list_items</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</child>
```